# How to understand SpatialDropout1D and when to use it?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, dropout

Occasionally I see some models are using `SpatialDropout1D` instead of `Dropout`. For example, in the Part of speech tagging neural network, they use:

```python
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(s_vocabsize, EMBED_SIZE,
                    input_length=MAX_SEQLEN))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.2)) ##This
model.add(GRU(HIDDEN_SIZE, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(RepeatVector(MAX_SEQLEN))
model.add(GRU(HIDDEN_SIZE, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(t_vocabsize)))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
```

According to Keras' documentation, it says:

> This version performs the same function as Dropout, however it drops
>   entire 1D feature maps instead of individual elements.

However, I am unable to understand the meaning of **entrie 1D feature**. More specifically, I am unable to visualize `SpatialDropout1D` in the same model explained in [quora](https://www.quora.com/How-does-the-dropout-method-work-in-deep-learning-And-why-is-it-claimed-to-be-an-effective-trick-to-improve-your-network).
Can someone explain this concept by using the same model as in quora?

Also, under what situation we will use `SpatialDropout1D` instead of `Dropout`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### The noise shape

In order to understand `SpatialDropout1D`, you should get used to the notion of the **noise shape**. In plain vanilla dropout, each element is kept or dropped independently. For example, if the tensor is `[2, 2, 2]`, each of 8 elements can be zeroed out depending on random coin flip (with certain "heads" probability); in total, there will be 8 independent coin flips and any number of values may become zero, from `0` to `8`.

Sometimes there is a need to do more than that. For example, one may need to drop the *whole slice* along `0` axis. The `noise_shape` in this case is `[1, 2, 2]` and the dropout involves only 4 independent random coin flips. The first component will either be kept together or be dropped together. The number of zeroed elements can be `0`, `2`, `4`, `6` or `8`. It cannot be `1` or `5`.

Another way to view this is to imagine that input tensor is in fact `[2, 2]`, but each value is double-precision (or multi-precision). Instead of dropping the bytes in the middle, the layer drops the full multi-byte value.

### Why is it useful?

The example above is just for illustration and isn't common in real applications. More realistic example is this: `shape(x) = [k, l, m, n]` and `noise_shape = [k, 1, 1, n]`. In this case, each batch and channel component will be kept independently, but each row and column will be kept or not kept together. In other words, the *whole* `[l, m]` *feature map* will be either kept or dropped.

You may want to do this to account for adjacent pixels correlation, especially in the early convolutional layers. Effectively, you want to prevent co-adaptation of pixels with its neighbors across the feature maps, and make them learn as if no other feature maps exist. This is exactly what `SpatialDropout2D` is doing: it promotes independence between feature maps.

The `SpatialDropout1D` is very similar: given `shape(x) = [k, l, m]` it uses `noise_shape = [k, 1, m]` and drops entire 1-D feature maps.

Reference: [Efficient Object Localization Using Convolutional Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4280) 
by Jonathan Tompson at al.

Comment: I was inspecting the source code, after reading the same description at Tensorflow's documentation, and I had the strong impression that this description is exactly the opposite of what the code actually does....

Comment: @DanielMöller Do you mean that `[k, 1, 1, n]` is not dropping the feature maps? My experiments show that they do. I'd say that keras doc is a bit misleading.

Comment: I'm not sure about what "feature maps" mean there regarding dimensions, but from what I could tell by [this code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py/#L2262), this is masking "samples" and "channels". (But I should experiment this as well before concluding).

Comment: By the code, `[k,1,1,n]` seems to be removing certain samples and certain channels, without touching any spatial dimension.

Comment: Ok.... I think my problem is text interpretation here... when I read "kept independently" I thought it meant "not discarded no matter what", but actually it probably means "may be discarded independently from other axes".

Comment: @DanielMöller yes, my understanding is the same, and I illustrate it by an example in my answer.

Comment: @Maxim When you explain the SpatialDropout1D, do you assume the input tensor is still `(2,2,2)`, and the noise_shape is `(1,2,2)`?
If so, I think the number of zero elements can be `0`, `2`, `4`, `6` or `8`.
And it cannot be `1`, `3`, `5`, `7`.
Am I correct?

Comment: @RavenCheuk oh, thanks for spotting it. Yes, it 0, 2, 4, 6, 8. I'll correct the typo

Comment: @Maxim I am reading this answer pretty late. It looks like we can use a custom noise shape with normal `Dropout` layer as well. So say, if my input tensor is of shape `10, 8, 5`, and I use a normal `Dropout` layer with noise_shape `10, 8, 1`, should tat give me the same output as using a `SpatialDropout1D`?

Comment: What do you mean by 8 independent coin flips as in the example that the data is [2, 2, 2] ? Here you have 3 data points, each coin flip corresponds only to 1 element in this array. So IMO there would be 3 coin flips here, or 3 independent events. Am I misunderstanding something.

Comment: @StayFoolish He's referring to the dimensions of the tensor. [2, 2, 2] are not the actual data points.

Answer (score 55):

To make it simple, I would first note that so-called feature maps (1D, 2D, etc.) is our regular channels. Let's look at examples:

1. `Dropout()`: Let's define 2D input: [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]. Dropout will consider every element independently, and may result in something like [[1, 0, 1], [0, 2, 2]]
2. `SpatialDropout1D()`: In this case result will look like [[1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 2]]. Notice that 2nd element was zeroed along **all** channels.